# Run Magento 1.9.4 using PHP 7.4

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.4

I know that magento 1.9.4 will support for php7.2. 
Php7.2 security support will end by this year nov 2020(https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

For considering security aspect, planning to run magento 1.9.4 using php 7.4.

can we run  magento 1.9.4 using php 7.4?

Please let me know (magento expert*).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Well Open Mage is a fork from magento 1 and supports PHP 7.4 and even 8.0 and still provides security patches

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

https://www.openmage.org/

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Magento1 does not fully support php7.4.

Did a PR some minutes ago here https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/1047/checks?check_run_id=783156607to fix last depraction warnings ...

Head over here ;)

---

Edit: last fixes are in, but lib/Zend is excldude from checks ... dont ask why, i dont know, so i'd recommend php7.3 for now.